# Change JavaFX progress bar style

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I want to modify this code and make the progress bar green:

```
.progress-bar > .bar {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(
        from 0px .75em to .75em 0px,
        repeat,
        -fx-accent 0%,
        -fx-accent 49%,
        derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 50%,
        derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 99%
        );
}
```

How I can modify the code to change the visual layout?

Comment: See the StackOverflow community wiki: [How can I style the ProgressBar component in JavaFX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19417246/how-can-i-style-the-progressbar-component-in-javafx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply overwrite the color constant `-fx-accent` the gradient colors are derived from:

```
.progress-bar > .bar {
    -fx-accent: green;
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(
        from 0px .75em to .75em 0px,
        repeat,
        -fx-accent 0%,
        -fx-accent 49%,
        derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 50%,
        derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 99%
        );
}
```