# Progress Bar size

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I'm using this cs code to set the color of a Progress Bar in JavaFX.

```
.progress-bar > .bar {
    -fx-accent: black;
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(
        from 0px .75em to .75em 0px,
        repeat,
        -fx-accent 0%,
        -fx-accent 49%,
        derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 50%,
        derive(-fx-accent, 30%) 99%
        );
}
```

I have a two questions: How I can add animation to this Progress Bar like Standard Windows animation:

[image]

Notice the white color into the Progress Bar. And Also I would like to make the Progress Bar little more thin. Can I control the size of the Progress Bar with CSS?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JAVAFX: Is it possible to set css by code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22817897/javafx-is-it-possible-to-set-css-by-code)

Answer (score 4):

All styling issues regarding the `ProgressBar` have already been answered in several places. You just have to do a little bit of research.

[Simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19881884/change-javafx-progress-bar-style)

[Example with gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19418709/1774643)

[Extended example with code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13372086/1774643)

Would mark as duplicate, but I'm curious if anyone pitches in with the actual Windows 8 progress bar gradient.