# How to get a small ProgressBar in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I'm trying to get an iTunes like progress bar that is very small (height of about 5px) but I can't seem to go any lower than 19 or 20px.

I tried setting -fx-max-height with no avail, also on the surrounding pane. Note that this value does indeed change the height - I just can't get it less than about 20px.

Any ideas how to achieve that? I'd like to avoid using a plain rectangle for indicating progress because of loss of semantic and support of assistive technology.

Thanks.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [How can I style the ProgressBar component in JavaFX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19417246/how-can-i-style-the-progressbar-component-in-javafx), but José has given such a great answer that I really don't want to mark is as such, and will just update the other answer to reference this :-)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that progress bar wiki out. It's really neat!

Comment: Thanks @jewelsea for your kind comments and updating the wiki answer with mine :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `ProgressBar` default styling is the reason why you can't reduce its height.

As we can see in the `modena.css` file for the `progress-bar` CSS selector:

```
.progress-bar > .bar {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom, derive(-fx-accent, -7%), derive(-fx-accent, 0%), derive(-fx-accent, -3%), derive(-fx-accent, -9%) );
    -fx-background-insets: 3 3 4 3;
    /*-fx-background-radius: 0.583em; *//* 7 */
    -fx-background-radius: 2;
    -fx-padding: 0.75em;
}
```

two CSS properties are responsible for this: `-fx-padding` for the height of the blue inner bar and `-fx-background-insets` for the height of the surrounding gray bar.

So you can customize this selector as you need. For instance, with these properties you will have 5 pixels height:

```
.progress-bar > .bar {
    -fx-background-insets: 1 1 2 1;
    -fx-padding: 0.20em;
}
```

No need for height settings on your code:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar(0.4);
    pb.setPrefWidth(200);
    StackPane root = new StackPane(pb);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 200);
    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("root.css").toExternalForm());
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

[image: Slim Progress Bar]

Comment: Thanks for this elaborate answer! :)

Comment: Elaborated answers like this really doesn't take too much, and you never know, they could be marked as a reference for others :)