# Fill JavaFX Shape from center of pane

Tags: javafx, geometry, shapes

I have a custom shape that I created with using a path in JavaFX. I want to fill the shape from the center of the screen to fill up in T seconds.

I currently have a simple version working with a rectangle that fills from the bottom but I cannot figure out how to apply this to a generic shape and fill it from the center of the screen.

This is an example of what I currently have where the color fills in from the bottom of the shape. (Marked by red arrow) [image: Current Code]

I would rather have the shape fill from the center point in the pane (Estimated with red dot) to the green arrow. [image: Goal of code]

```
package com.example.javafx21;

import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Pane pane = new Pane();

        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
        stackPane.setLayoutX(50);
        stackPane.setLayoutY(50);

        Rectangle outlineRect = new Rectangle(100, 100);
        outlineRect.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        outlineRect.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);


        Rectangle fillRect = new Rectangle(100, 100);
        fillRect.setFill(Color.BLUE);


        Rectangle maskRect = new Rectangle(100, 100);
        maskRect.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        maskRect.yProperty().bind(fillRect.yProperty().add(fillRect.heightProperty()));
        fillRect.setClip(maskRect);

        stackPane.getChildren().addAll(fillRect, outlineRect);

        Button button = new Button("Fill Rectangle");
        button.setLayoutX(75);
        button.setLayoutY(250);


        pane.getChildren().addAll(stackPane, button);


        TranslateTransition transition = new TranslateTransition(Duration.seconds(2), maskRect);
        transition.setFromY(0);
        transition.setFromX(0);
        transition.setToY(-fillRect.getHeight());
//        transition.setToX(-fillRect.getWidth());
        transition.setCycleCount(1);
        transition.setAutoReverse(false);


        button.setOnAction(e -> transition.play());

        pane.setOnMouseClicked(mouseEvent -> {

            System.out.println("mouse X = " + mouseEvent.getX() + " Mouse Y = " + mouseEvent.getY());
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 300, 300);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Rectangle Fill Transition");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Related [various options for styling the JavaFX progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19417246/how-can-i-style-the-progressbar-component-in-javafx) and [making a percentage of a linear gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69841786/is-it-possible-to-make-a-percentage-of-a-linear-gradient-in-javafx).

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a `LinearGradient` for the fill. Given some proportion `prop` of the rectangle you want filled, you can use the following color stops in the linear gradient:

```
new Stop(0, Color.BLUE),
new Stop(prop, Color.BLUE),
new Stop(prop, Color.WHITE),
new Stop(1, Color.WHITE)
```

The effect will be not to create a "gradient", as such, but a sharp transition from `BLUE` to `WHITE` at the value of `prop`. So when `prop` is `0`, the rectangle will be all `WHITE`, and when `prop` is `1` it will be all `BLUE`.

You can fill diagonally as you ask by making `startX=1`, `startY=1`, `endX=0`, `endY=0` and using a proportional linear gradient.

Finally, you need to animate the gradient. You can do this by defining the proportion as a `DoubleProperty` and animating its value with a `Timeline`, and the use [the `map` method introduced in JavaFX 19](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76971752/what-are-the-use-cases-for-the-new-methods-introduced-to-observablevalue-in-java) to map its value to the appropriate linear gradient.

Here is the whole thing put together:

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.CycleMethod;
import javafx.scene.paint.LinearGradient;
import javafx.scene.paint.Stop;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Pane pane = new Pane();

        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
        stackPane.setLayoutX(50);
        stackPane.setLayoutY(50);



        Rectangle outlineRect = new Rectangle(100, 100);
        outlineRect.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        outlineRect.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        DoubleProperty fillProportion = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);

        Rectangle fillRect = new Rectangle(100, 100);
//        fillRect.setFill(Color.BLUE);
        fillRect.fillProperty().bind(fillProportion.map(prop ->
            new LinearGradient(1, 1, 0, 0, true, CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE,
                new Stop(0, Color.BLUE),
                new Stop(prop.doubleValue(), Color.BLUE),
                new Stop(prop.doubleValue(), Color.WHITE),
                new Stop(1, Color.WHITE)
            )
        ));

//        Rectangle maskRect = new Rectangle(100, 100);
//        maskRect.setFill(Color.WHITE);
//        maskRect.yProperty().bind(fillRect.yProperty().add(fillRect.heightProperty()));
//        fillRect.setClip(maskRect);

        stackPane.getChildren().addAll(fillRect, outlineRect);

        Button button = new Button("Fill Rectangle");
        button.setLayoutX(75);
        button.setLayoutY(250);


        pane.getChildren().addAll(stackPane, button);


//        TranslateTransition transition = new TranslateTransition(Duration.seconds(2), maskRect);
//        transition.setFromY(0);
//        transition.setFromX(0);
//        transition.setToY(-fillRect.getHeight());
////        transition.setToX(-fillRect.getWidth());
//        transition.setCycleCount(1);
//        transition.setAutoReverse(false);
        Timeline transition = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(fillProportion, 0)),
                new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2), new KeyValue(fillProportion, 1))
        );

        button.setOnAction(e -> transition.play());

        pane.setOnMouseClicked(mouseEvent -> {
            System.out.println("mouse X = " + mouseEvent.getX() + " Mouse Y = " + mouseEvent.getY());
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 300, 300);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Rectangle Fill Transition");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```