# Have a problem customizing ProgressBar in JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, progress-bar

Code to style ProgressBar:

```
songProgressBar.setStyle("-fx-accent: green;-fx-control-inner-background: black;-fx-text-box-border: green;");
```

What I get

[image]

Why is bottom border white?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but you can cross-check against the [default progress bar CSS in modena.css](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/fdc88341f1df8fb9c99356ada54b25124b77ea6e/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css#L1165) which might help you work it out.  There is also a [StackOverflow community wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19417246/how-can-i-style-the-progressbar-component-in-javafx) on styling progress bars which may or may not help you.

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer